# preg_replace not working when add <a href

Tags: php, replace

i need to do this

replacing `<a href="forum.php?id=1">title</a>`
with      `<a href="f-1-title.html">title</a>`

i do this patren

```
$prased_template=preg_replace('#<a href="forum.php?id=(.*?)">(.+?)</a>@','test=\\3',$template);
```

but its not work , i need to get the ID and Title to put it in second value

how !

Answer (score 0):

```
$replaced = preg_replace('#<a href="forum.php\?id=(\d+)">([^<]+)</a>#i','<a href="f-$1-$2.html">$2</a>', $template);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex has a couple of issues. First, the delimiters don't match. You open with `#` but close with `@`; this won't work. Stick with one. You also aren't escaping other characters in the string. Use this and it should work:

```
#<a href="forum\.php\?id=(.*?)">(.+?)</a>#
```

Comment: thank you , but your regex work only when i remove (<a href=") from the patren how to resolve it

Comment: Works for me.. `$template = '<a href="forum.php?id=1">title</a>';` `$prased_template=preg_replace('#<a href="forum\.php\?id=(.*?)">(.+?)</a>#','test=\\3',$template);` `echo $prased_template;` `test=`

Comment: wired its not work on my board :) its onlu work if i remove <a href=" from the regex